# how to classificate transactional data (database/sql/view)

Tags: sql, transactions, classification

I want to classificate transactional data and my table with the data looks as follows:

> **ID - COLUMN1 - COLUMN2 - COLUMN3**
>
> 0 - **A** - B - C
>
> 0 - A - **D** - C
>
> 0 - E - B - **C**
>
> 1 - A - B - C
>
> 1 - A - B - C
>
> 2 - **A** - **D** - C
>
> 2 - A - B - **F**
>
> 3 - A - D - C
>
> 3 - **A** - **B** - **F**
>
> 3 - A - B - C

The Output should be the following:

> **ID - CLASSIFICATION**
>
> 0 - critical (because of the pattern "A D C")
>
> 1 - uncritical (no conspicuous pattern detected)
>
> 2 - critical (A D F)
>
> 3 - critical (A D F)

Just a few examples. The patterns can be in one row or in a complete transaction (a few rows but one identical ID)

Now i want to solve the problem with no coding, just with table/view and SQL. i am working on SAP HANA.

The problem is, how to create a calculated column or something else, which searches a transactional data table and classifies one (!) transaction (for example ID "0") as critical, because the pattern "ADC" occurs?

Comment: ABD or ADC?  And, are you requiring that the positions be on different rows?  Or is the second row sufficient for making id 0 critical?

Comment: ADC, sorry. Its just a example! The positions **can be** on different rows, but don't have to be.

Answer (score 0):

The following comes close to what you want:

```
select distinct t1.id
from table t1 join
     table t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.column1 = 'A' and t2.column2 = 'B' join
     table t3
     on t1.id = t3.id and t3.column3 = 'D';
```

It is unclear whether you want the values in different rows.  If so, then you need a row identifier that is unique, and you can include this in the logic:

```
select distinct t1.id
from table t1 join
     table t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.column1 = 'A' and t2.column2 = 'B' and
        t1.rowunique <> t2.rowunique join
     table t3
     on t1.id = t3.id and t3.column3 = 'D' and
        t3.rowunique not in (t1.rowunique, t2.rowunique);
```

Comment: i will try it. I added two other examples. The patterns can occur in one row or more rows - just the ID is identical. I think then i should use your second statement?

Comment: If the pattern can occur in one row, then the first query is fine.